# laravel one to one relation return as one object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a One to One relation. I would like to return json data, in which one to one ralation model show like one object, not as child.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['email'];

    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
}
```

I want to retun json in controller, like:

```
[
   {
      email: "test@test.test",
      first_name: "Teszt",
      last_name: "Jhon"
   },
   {
      email: "test2@test2.test",
      first_name: "Teszt2",
      last_name: "Jhon2"
   }
]
```

But if I do this:

```
return User::with('profile')->get();
```

Only get this:

```
[
   {
      email: "test@test.test",
      profile: {
         first_name: "Teszt",
         last_name: "Jhon"
      }
   },
   {
      email: "test2@test2.test",
      profile: {
         first_name: "Teszt2",
         last_name: "Jhon2"
      }
   }
]
```

What is the best solution to get the first json variation?

Comment: you can't do it with a built in method. You would need to loop on the profile attributes and add them to the user yourself.

Comment: you are probably going to create the array yourself, since the current result is the way the relation is setup. So i suggest looping the users and create an array, pass it to `response()->json($array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and `$appends` to achieve this:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
    ...

    public function getFirstNameAttribute() {
        return $this->profile->first_name;
    }

    public function getLastNameAttribute() {
        return $this->profile->last_name;
    }
    ...
}
```

And then

```php
User::get()->toJson();
```

will output:

```
[
   {
      "email": "test@test.test",
      "first_name": "Teszt",
      "last_name": "Jhon"
   },
   {
      "email": "test2@test2.test",
      "first_name": "Teszt2",
      "last_name": "Jhon2"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is just for the JSON response you can use [a resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

Create it using

```
php artisan make:resource UserResource
```

Then in your resource's `toArray` method customise what will be returned:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'email' => $this->email,
        'first_name' => $this->profile->first_name,
        'last_name' => $this->profile->last_name
    ];
}
```

You can then use it as :

```
UserResource::withoutWrapping(); // If you don't want data wrapped in a data entry
return UserResource::collection(User::with('profile')->get());
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a `JSON` response, you can use `accessors`, `appends()` and `hidden()` logic to handle this:

```
$users = User::with('profile')->get();
return response()->json(['users' => $users']);
```

Then, in your `User.php` Model:

```
protected $hidden = ['profile']; // Hide `profile` from `JSON` response
protected $appends ['first_name', 'last_name']; // Auto-append to `JSON` response

// `$user->first_name` in `PHP`, or `user.first_name` in `JSON`
public function getFirstNameAttribute(){
    return $this->profile ? $this->profile->first_name : null;
}

// `$user->last_name` in `PHP`, or `user.last_name` in `JSON`
public function getLastNameAttribute)(){
    return $this->profile ? $this->profile->last_name : null;
}
```

With this code, all records in the `users` array will look like your desired output above.